# Parsing table html using JSoup

Tags: android, html, parsing

Sorry for my english. I use [jsop](http://jsoup.org/) libruary and i try parsing data from table. But i have not good result. I have this html:

```
<table class="charTable">
<tr>
<th><a href="processor.html">№</a></th>
<th><a href="processor_model.html" >Модель</a></th>
</tr>
<tr valign=top  style="background-color:#FFFFFF">
<td><nobr><input type="checkbox" name="887" class="compare_check">1</nobr></td>
<td><nobr><b><a href="./processor_887.html">Intel Core i7-4940MX (Haswell)</a></b></nobr></td><td>3100</td>
</tr>
<tr>.....</tr>
<tr>.....</tr>
<tr>.....</tr>
<tr>.....</tr>
</table >
```

I need take this string:

```
Intel Core i7-4940MX (Haswell)
```

I do like this:

```
Elements text = doc.select("tbody > tr > td > nobr > b > a");
```

And he output me

```
<a href="./processor_887.html">Intel Core i7-4940MX (Haswell)</a>
```

Comment: "... > b > a").first().text() work?

Comment: @Tim yes, thanks. I did like this `doc.select("tbody > tr > td > nobr > b > a").first().toString()` but it output only one times. I thins i need get Elements and take for that elent. I will try

Comment: ah, ok. so iterate thru text, should work. for (Element e: text) System.out.println(e.text());

Comment: np, accept answer if it worked out for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the text() method of the Element class to grab the node value text.

e.g.
for (Element e: text) { System.out.println(e.text()); }